# Wordpress make text appears on scroll

Tags: wordpress

I am using the wordpress Hestia theme.

I am doing an education research project and developing a website http://foresighthk.net.

I would like to make my words appear only when scrollbar scrolls down.

May I know if anyone would know how to do that animation in wordpress site?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can go to animate.css to search for the desired css effect then add into the .css file